# Python 3 CSV file giving UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte error when I print

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I have the following code in Python 3, which is meant to print out each line in a csv file.

```
import csv
with open('my_file.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '|')
    for line in lines:
        print(' '.join(line))
```

But when I run it, it gives me this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 7386: invalid start byte
```

I looked through the csv file, and it turns out that if I take out a single ñ (little n with a tilde on top), every line prints out fine.

My problem is that I've looked through a bunch of different solutions to similar problems, but I still have no idea how to fix this, what to decode/encode, etc. Simply taking out the ñ character in the data is NOT an option.

Comment: Could you share a row of your csv file having ñ.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

We know the file contains the byte `b'\x96'` since it is mentioned in the error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 7386: invalid start byte
```

Now we can write a little script to find out if there are any encodings where `b'\x96'` decodes to  `ñ`:

```
import pkgutil
import encodings
import os

def all_encodings():
    modnames = set([modname for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(
        path=[os.path.dirname(encodings.__file__)], prefix='')])
    aliases = set(encodings.aliases.aliases.values())
    return modnames.union(aliases)

text = b'\x96'
for enc in all_encodings():
    try:
        msg = text.decode(enc)
    except Exception:
        continue
    if msg == 'ñ':
        print('Decoding {t} with {enc} is {m}'.format(t=text, enc=enc, m=msg))
```

which yields

```
Decoding b'\x96' with mac_roman is ñ
Decoding b'\x96' with mac_farsi is ñ
Decoding b'\x96' with mac_croatian is ñ
Decoding b'\x96' with mac_arabic is ñ
Decoding b'\x96' with mac_romanian is ñ
Decoding b'\x96' with mac_iceland is ñ
Decoding b'\x96' with mac_turkish is ñ
```

Therefore, try changing

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
```

to one of those encodings, such as:

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'r', encoding='mac_roman', newline='') as csvfile:
```

Comment: Its work for me, but why with  mac_roman and not utf-8 as encoding?

Answer (score 40):

`with open('my_file.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as csvfile:`

ñ character is not listed on UTC-8 encoding. To fix the issue, you may use ISO-8859-1 encoding instead. For more details about this encoding, you may refer to the link below:
https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html

Comment: This solution worked for me. Wasted hours to find this answer.

Answer (score 9):

For others who hit the same error shown in the subject, watch out for the file encoding of your csv file. Its possible it is not utf-8. I just noticed that LibreOffice created a utf-16 encoded file for me today without prompting me although I could not reproduce this.

If you try to open a utf-16 encoded document using `open(... encoding='utf-8')`, you will get the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

To fix either specify 'utf-16' encoding or change the encoding of the csv.

Comment: I had this exact problem. After pulling my hair out, I found this suggestion. FWIW, if you are using Excel 2013+, save the file as "CSV (MS DOS)"

Comment: +1 Yes, this is a common gotcha. For CSV files, if Excel saved a file with some 'utf-16' encoding you didn't want then _even when you've removed the offending unicode characters_ you want to make sure the file format is 'CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (.csv)' when you save it (or 'save as' it).

Answer (score 9):

I also faced the issue with python 3 and my issue got resolved using the encoding type as **utf-16**

```
with open('data.csv', newline='',encoding='utf-16') as csvfile:
```

Answer (score 1):

easy... just open it in Excel or OpenOffice calc, use text as columns, select `,`, and then just save the file as `.csv`... it takes me one day and several hour of search in google... but at the end i figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution is to open the csv file in notepad and select "Save As" in "File" dropdown list. Choose "Save as type" to "All files(*.*)". Select "UTF-8 Encoding" in Encoding dropdown list and put ".csv" extension to the file name

Answer (score 0):

Just try UTF 16 for the file that may include characters rather than English ones and that's why UTF-16 is implemented for it. 8 and 16 implementations are the same unicode, yet the only difference is the bits number so it 16 will handle character like `~` while 8 will not, just `a-zA-Z0-9` characters

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='UTF-16') as csvfile:
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found

```
import codecs
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

def lire_csv(nom_fichier):
    with codecs.open(nom_fichier, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as fichier_csv:
        lecteur = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in fichier_csv), delimiter=';')
        donnees = list(lecteur)
    return donnees
```

Answer (score -3):

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
```

**Try opening the file like above**

Comment: That won't work, because the error message indicates it's already trying to use the UTF-8 codec.

Comment: ..though another encoding might work. In my case latin-1 did the job

Comment: I dont understand why this answer has downvotes. To set the correct file encoding has definitively solved the issue.