# Django csv UnicodeDecodeError during opening excel file

Tags: django, csv

I have a model: (Python 3.5)

```
class Model(models.Model):
  import_file = models.FileField(upload_to="import")

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    with open(self.import_file.name) as csvfile:
      reader = DictReader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
      for line in reader:
         print (line)
```

I got

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 15: invalid start byte
The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: !f�}
```

I tried with utf16, but then I got error with BOM.

Do you guys have any ideas?

**EDIT1**
I've just tried

```
...
with open(self.import_file.name, encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:     
...
```

Still same error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 15: invalid start byte
```

**EDIT2**

If I changed encoding to ISO-8859-1 I got:

```
line contains NULL byte
```

Comment: Try `open(self.import_file.name, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: I've tried, pleas see an edit1

Comment: I have same problem with opening csv. In my case, the problem was solved by this code
`reader = csv.DictReader(self.utf_8_encoder(cd['csv'].file.read().splitlines()),
                                fieldnames=CountPointImport.get_import_fields())`

where utf_8_encoder is a function: 
`def utf_8_encoder(self, unicode_csv_data):
        for line in unicode_csv_data:
            yield line.decode('ascii', 'ignore')`

Comment: Try changing the encoding. Something similar happened to me and it only worked with this encoding - `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 CSV file giving UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte error when I print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504319/python-3-csv-file-giving-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-err)