# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 2: invalid start byte, tried all encoding styles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, flask

```
ad
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 826, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 841, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 920, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1052, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1083, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1220, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1238, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1429, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

I am getting above error while reading my CSV

to rectify this I used unicode escape:

```
csv_df=pd.read_csv(file_path,header=0,squeeze=True,dtype=str,keep_default_na=False,encoding='unicode_escape')
```

However,
Now I am getting \xa0 for space between two words:

```
'ObjectStatus': 'IN\xa0SERVICE'
```

My CSV has:

```
Key          Values
RequestID   
ObjectType   CONTAINER
ObjectName   INMUNVMBMHPBNB6001ENBCMW005
ObjectStatus IN SERVICE
ObjectType   CONTAINER
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504319/python-3-csv-file-giving-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-err

Comment: `\xa0` is a Unicode U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE.  Python is displaying the string with a Unicode escape sequence so you can see it isn't a regular space.   If you `print` the value, it will show as a space.

Comment: Actually, this dictionary is passed as a request to zeep client obiect. There it is getting converted to question mark character**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unicode_escape` codec is for *literal* escape codes (length 4 `\\xa0` vs. length 1 `\xa0`).  As displayed, that's just Python's debug representation of the string, and it prints `\xa0` to show that it isn't a regular space.  You're file is probably encoded in `cp1252` or `latin1`, as `\xa0` is the `NO-BREAK SPACE` in those encodings.

Example:

```
>>> d = {'ObjectStatus': 'IN\xa0SERVICE'}
>>> d
{'ObjectStatus': 'IN\xa0SERVICE'}
>>> print(d['ObjectStatus'])
IN SERVICE
```

Comment: Actually, this dictionary is passed as a request to zeep client obiect. There it is getting converted to question mark character

Answer (score 0):

For me below has worked.
Using str.replace() I have replaced all values in the column having '\xa0' with ' '

```
csv_df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0, squeeze=True,dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)

csv_df['Values'] = csv_df['Values'].astype(str).str.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')
```

I had to pass these values into an another function which created an XML, tried all encodings, none worked.